# How can I add multiple cells to a TableView without reloading the TableView? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays. One with data for the cells. The second one is empty. In the second array, I add 10 elements from the first one and output this array to the table. If there are more than 10 elements in the first array, then I make the "upload more" button visible. How can I add 10 more cells to the table without reloading the first 10?

Comment: Why don't you want to reload the table?

Comment: Add the items to the data source array and call `insertRows(at:with:)` on the table view passing the appropriate index paths.